# JQ: Convert Array to Array, access upper elements and position

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I got the following source:

```
{
    "id": "FOO11100",
    "Published": {
        "$date": "2020-04-02T15:15:00Z"
    },
    "Modified": {
        "$date": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
    },
    "last-modified": {
        "$date": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
    },
    "access": {
        "authentication": "SINGLE",
        "complexity": "LOW",
        "vector": "NETWORK"
    },
    "available_product": [
        "custom:foo:a:roxy:1.8",
        "custom:foo:a:roxy:1.9",
        "custom:foo:o:ianu:10.0"
    ]
}
```

I want to get something like that:

```
{
  "entries": [
  {
    "parent": {
      "processid": "FOO11100",
      "published": "2020-04-02T15:15:00Z",
      "modified": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z",
      "access_authentication": "SINGLE",
      "access_complexity": "LOW",
      "access_vector": "NETWORK"
    },
    "childs": [
        {
          "processid": "FOO11100",
          "childid": 1,
          "type": "Application",
          "name": "roxy",
          "score": "1.8",
          "lastupdate": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
        },
        {
          "processid": "FOO11100",
          "childid": 2,
          "type": "Application",
          "name": "roxy",
          "score": "1.9",
          "lastupdate": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
        },
        {
          "processid": "FOO11100",
          "childid": 3,
          "type": "Operation",
          "name": "ianu",
          "score": "10.0",
          "lastupdate": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The upper part is no problem, but in the lower part I want to iterate over the elements within .available_product and access:

- id and last-modified outside of the array for processid and lastupdate within the new object
- the position of the element within the array for childid
- the tokenized text part 3 to translate it (a=Application, o=Operation)

Currently i have that:

```
{entries: 
 [
  { parent: 
   {
    processid: .id, 
    published: .Published."$date", 
    modified: ."last-modified"."$date", 
    access_authentication: .access.authentication, 
    access_complexity: .access.complexity, 
    access_vector: .access.vector
   }, 
   childs: .available_product
  }
 ]
}
```

but I dont have any luck with the array processing.

any help appreciated

Comment: You're looking for something like [this](https://jqplay.org/s/oVxSckedjo). Next time you ask a question, include a [mre].

Comment: Thanks so much, resolved my problem!!!

Comment: @oguzismail It's always a shame to find a comment with a dead link that apparently solved the problem. But no answer on StackOverflow itself. This is not really helpful for future visitors. Care to add the answer to this question? (and NB the plural of "child" is "children").

Answer (score 0):

The following works for your given input:

```
. as { id: $processid, "last-modified": { "$date": $lastupdate } }
| { a:"Application", o:"Operation" } as $types
| {
    entries: [
        {
            parent: {
                $processid, 
                published: .Published."$date", 
                modified: $lastupdate,
                access_authentication: .access.authentication, 
                access_complexity: .access.complexity, 
                access_vector: .access.vector
            },
            children: .available_product
                | map(
                    split(":") as [$prefix, $name, $typeid, $name, $score]
                    | $types[$typeid] as $type
                    | { $processid, $type, $name, $score, $lastupdate }
                )
                | to_entries
                | map({childid: (.key+1)} + .value)
        }
    ]
}
```

Generating the output:

```
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "parent": {
        "processid": "FOO11100",
        "published": "2020-04-02T15:15:00Z",
        "modified": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z",
        "access_authentication": "SINGLE",
        "access_complexity": "LOW",
        "access_vector": "NETWORK"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "childid": 1,
          "processid": "FOO11100",
          "type": "Application",
          "name": "roxy",
          "score": "1.8",
          "lastupdate": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
        },
        {
          "childid": 2,
          "processid": "FOO11100",
          "type": "Application",
          "name": "roxy",
          "score": "1.9",
          "lastupdate": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
        },
        {
          "childid": 3,
          "processid": "FOO11100",
          "type": "Operation",
          "name": "ianu",
          "score": "10.0",
          "lastupdate": "2020-12-24T16:15:00Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

An alternative version which generates the same output could be:

```
.id as $processid
| ."last-modified"."$date" as $lastupdate
| {
    entries: [
        {
            parent: {
                $processid, 
                published: .Published."$date", 
                modified: $lastupdate,
                access_authentication: .access.authentication, 
                access_complexity: .access.complexity, 
                access_vector: .access.vector
            },
            children: .available_product
                | to_entries
                | map(
                    .value |= split(":")
                    | {
                        $processid,
                        childid: (.key+1),
                        type: { a:"Application", o:"Operation" }[.value[2]],
                        name: .value[3],
                        score: .value[4],
                        $lastupdate
                    }
                )
        }
    ]
}
```